# How to compute density function of $Y=X-\lfloor X \rfloor$?

Tags: probability, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We're given that X is a continous r.v. and has a density function of $f_X(x)$ and we're asked to find the density function of $Y=X-\lfloor X \rfloor$ in terms of $f_X(x)$.

We're also given the **hint** : to use the expression $P(Y \le x ,\lfloor X \rfloor =i)$ where $i$ is integer.

$$P(Y \le x ,\lfloor X \rfloor =i) = P(X - \lfloor X \rfloor  \le x, \lfloor X \rfloor  = i)$$

$$=P(X - i \le x, \lfloor X \rfloor  = i)$$
$$=P(X \le x + i, \lfloor X \rfloor  = i)$$
$$=P(X \le x + i,i \le X \lt  i + 1)$$

I tried to expand it but this doesn't lead to anywhere. (I'm glad to see any answer with or without the hint). The follow up question in the book is to specify $f_Y(y)$ if $X \sim exp(\lambda)$. (So I need to find a "general" form first)

Comment: @StubbornAtom Although the problem doesn't say anything if $X$ can take negative values, I'll make my life easy and say that $X$ can only be a natural number. So, for now let's throw away the hint.

If $ \epsilon \in (0,1)$, then $P(X - \left \lfloor{X}\right \rfloor \leq \epsilon)$ is 
$$f_Y(y)=\frac {d}{dy}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \int_{i}^{i + \epsilon} f_X(x) \,dx $$

Does that make any sense ? ( I also added some extra info in the main question, that might help with the solution)

Comment: Thinking first about the values $Y$ may take would help. Obviously, $P(0\leqslant Y<1)=1$ hence computing $F_Y(y)$ for $y<0$ or $y\geqslant1$ is absurd. Next, for every $0\leqslant y<1$, $$\{Y\leqslant y\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}\{n\leqslant X<n+y\}$$ Oops, exercise solved!

Comment: Sorry, each event $\{n\leqslant X<n+y\}$ should read $\{n\leqslant X\leqslant n+y\}$.

Comment: @Did are you saying that :
$$ P(Y\leq y) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty P(i \leq X \leq i + y) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty {F_X(i+y)-F_X(i)}$$ where $X= Y + \lfloor X \rfloor$ so all that is left is to take a derivative and I would get my answer ? thank you !!!

Comment: Yes, provided $P(X>0)=1$, otherwise the sum on $i\geqslant0$ should read as a sum on $i\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments:** The distribution of $Y$ depends on the distribution of $X,$ so
your initial job is to express $f_Y$ in terms of $f_X.$

The top histogram below approximates the distribution of $Y$ originating from
$X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(rate=0.1)$ and the bottom histogram imitates
the distribution of $Y$ originating from $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,10).$
Each is based on a million observations from the relevant $X.$

[image]

R code to make the figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # enables two plots per figure
 x1 = rexp(10^6, 1/10); y1 = x1 - floor(x1)
  hist(y1, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="From Exponential")
 x2 = runif(10^6, 1, 10); y2 = x2 - floor(x2)
  hist(y2, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="From Uniform")
par(mfrow=c(1,1)) # return to single plot mode
```

The distribution of $Y$ is a mixture of several or many random
variables with support $[0,1].$ For these two simple cases all
of the 'pieces' are of about the same shape. When I did this for $\mathsf{Norm}(100,10)$ it seems that the pieces are of different shapes but have roughly a uniform
distribution when combined.

For the follow-up question, I suppose you are meant to use an exponential
distribution for $X$ as I did in my first simulation.